# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web.config Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am sure it is something very simple that I am missing.  When I run my ASP web app it errors out in the browser with the following:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file
required to service this request. Please review the specific error details
below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element.

Source Error: 

Line 23:   <system.web>  ## This line is highlighted in red ##
Line 24:       <identity impersonate="true"/>
Line 25:       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Here is the part of my Web.config where I am getting the error.

```
...
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
...
```

Comment: The only thing I see that's wonky is the missing space after `identity impersonate="true"`, but that shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: First, is your XML Valid? Validate your xml: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: try removing identity impersonate if you do not need it?

Comment: Please post, full config code.

Comment: You probably have an unclosed block earlier in the config file